VSCode enable focus terminal to display terminal name
I accidently uncheck the Focus option while right-clicking the top/header of the terminal bar. The terminal name that used to be displayed there has now disappear (see screenshot).
I have tried this Focus but apparently it's not the same Focus option. Could you please let me know how to enable Focus again to display the terminal name? Thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Right-click on another icon near there - like the split or garbage can - and choose Focus Terminal and the terminal name should come back.
Choosing Reset Menu would bring it back as well, but perhaps you made other changes you don't want reset.
